# How to inject message into Twitter's private message input via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am writing script to send message to accounts and I have everything set up, the only one thing is left. I am trying to inject message into Twitter's DM. It can't be simple like:

```
$('.public-DraftStyleDefault-block').children('span').append('<span data-text="true">some injected text</span>');
```

Seems like Twitter is reacting to key event and triggering something. Is there any way in Javascript to inject my own text so Twitter picks it up?

[image]